# I have problem with removing last item from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
nums = [0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2]

val = 2

for i in nums:
    if i == val:
        nums.remove(i)
    else:
         continue
print(nums)
```

Result is [0,1,3,0,4,2] instead of [0,1,3,0,4]

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe I am a little bit confused because in the title you ask for removing just the last item but in the question you ask for an expected result. I just took your code and make it work to get the expected output with a **list comprehension**. It looks like this:

```
nums_new = [i for i in nums if i != val]
```

You can ofcourse name nums_new to only nums.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake becomes clear if you print your data inside the loop:

```
nums = [0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2]

val = 2

for i in nums:
    if i == val:
        nums.remove(i)
    print(i, nums)
print(nums)
```

Output:

```
0 [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2]
1 [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2]
2 [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2]
3 [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2]
0 [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2]
4 [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 2]
2 [0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 2]
[0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 2]
```

Note:

- `i` goes through 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., i.e., *not* two 2s in a row. That's because you remove the first 2, but "the loop" doesn't care, it still goes to the next position in the list, which then holds the value 3.
- You do find the 2 at the end, but since `remove` removes the first occurrence, it removes the earlier 2.

Answer (score -1):

You have a few options:

**Filter**

```
your_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2]
filtered_values = filter(lambda value: value != 2, your_list)
```

The first argument is the filtering function, the second is your values - whatever evaluates to `False` is *removed* from the list.

**List comprehension**

```
your_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2]
filtered_values = [value for value in your_list if value != 2]
```

There are many other ways of doing it, although those are the most common ways of doing it.

Answer (score -3):

You can also do this with the `NumPy` module:

```py
import numpy as np
# generate 20 random integers between 0 (inclusive) and 5 (exclusive)
myarr = np.random.randint(0, 5, 20) 
print(myarr)
[0 2 0 1 2 0 3 0 0 0 3 4 1 3 1 4 1 0 4 4]
val = 2
myarr = np.delete(myarr, np.where(myarr == val))
print(myarr)
[0 0 1 0 3 0 0 0 3 4 1 3 1 4 1 0 4 4]
```

```py
myarr = np.delete(myarr, np.where(myarr == val))
```

In that line we do the following: from the array `myarr`, delete the elements whenever that element equals `val`.

The same can be achieved with your initial list, by first converting it to a numpy array:

```py
nums = np.array(nums)
```

Comment: I think that is completely overkill here haha. But yes if you get a huge array and you want the code to work fast then numpy is the way to go

Comment: why so seriousserious ?